# T-SQL - Total difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, datediff

I have two tables, **Orders** & **Order History**, the Orders table has the **Order Number** and the **Order Date** which is the date that the order was actually placed.

This is demonstrated in the below schema and demonstration data;

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders
(
OrderNumber INT,
OrderDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #Orders (OrderNumber,OrderDate)
VALUES
(001,'2019-04-16 07:08:08.567'),
(002,'2019-03-22 07:08:08.567'),
(003,'2019-06-30 07:08:08.567'),
(004,'2019-01-05 07:08:08.567'),
(005,'2019-02-19 07:08:08.567')
```

The **Order audit** table also contains the **Order Number** and the **Event Date** which is the date that the order status changed.

This is demonstrated in the below schema and demonstration data.

```
CREATE TABLE #Order_Audit
(
OrderNumber INT,
EventDate DATETIME,
Status INT
)

INSERT INTO #Order_Audit (OrderNumber,EventDate,Status)
VALUES
(001,'2019-04-16 07:08:08.567',1),
(001,'2019-04-19 07:08:08.567',2),
(001,'2019-04-22 07:08:08.567',3),
(001,'2019-04-28 07:08:08.567',4),
(001,'2019-04-30 07:08:08.567',5),
(002,'2019-03-22 07:08:08.567',1),
(002,'2019-03-24 07:08:08.567',2),
(002,'2019-03-26 07:08:08.567',3),
(002,'2019-04-01 07:08:08.567',4),
(002,'2019-04-10 07:08:08.567',5),
(003,'2019-06-30 07:08:08.567',1),
(003,'2019-07-15 07:08:08.567',2),
(003,'2019-07-19 07:08:08.567',3),
(003,'2019-07-20 07:08:08.567',4),
(003,'2019-07-21 07:08:08.567',5),
(004,'2019-01-05 07:08:08.567',1),
(004,'2019-01-06 07:08:08.567',2),
(004,'2019-01-07 07:08:08.567',3),
(004,'2019-01-08 07:08:08.567',4),
(004,'2019-01-09 07:08:08.567',5),
(005,'2019-02-19 07:08:08.567',1),
(005,'2019-03-19 07:08:08.567',2),
(005,'2019-03-21 07:08:08.567',3),
(005,'2019-03-22 07:08:08.567',4),
(005,'2019-03-23 07:08:08.567',5)
```

Below is the query that I have at the moment, it will give me the difference between the **Event Date** and the **Order Date** that the order was placed.

The query has been simplified however the key columns are included. This is being executed on ***SQL Server 2012 SP4***

```
SELECT  
    O.OrderNumber,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,O.OrderDate,OA.EventDate) AS [Day-Diff]
FROM #Orders O

INNER JOIN #Order_Audit OA ON OA.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
```

The above query outputs like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      OrderNumber    |     DayDiff      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |         14       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |         19       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

What I actually need is a query that will output more like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      OrderNumber    |     DayDiff      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          001        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Total      |        14        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          002        |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Total      |        19        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

However I can't figure out how to get the difference between the **Order Date** and the most recent **Event Date** for each order and add it below that group of order events (as shown above) - I am not even sure it is possible in T-SQL and should possibly be handled at the application level.

Comment: How do you calculate 14 and 19 as total for 001 and 002? Is this the last value per OrderNumber?

Comment: @mkRabbani Yeah, 14 & 19 would be the difference between the most recent **Event Date** from the Order_Audit table and the date the order was placed from the Orders table for each **Order Number**

Comment: Added an anser. Hope this will help you. @BonzaOwl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below. I have created the Total label as OrderNumber + Total for ordering.

```
SELECT  
   CAST(O.OrderNumber AS VARCHAR) +  ' Total' OrderNumber,
    MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY,O.OrderDate,OA.EventDate)) AS [Day-Diff]
FROM #Orders O

INNER JOIN #Order_Audit OA ON OA.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber
GROUP BY CAST(O.OrderNumber AS VARCHAR) +  ' Total'

UNION ALL

SELECT  
   CAST(O.OrderNumber AS VARCHAR) OrderNumber,
   NULL AS [Day-Diff]
FROM #Orders O

INNER JOIN #Order_Audit OA ON OA.OrderNumber = O.OrderNumber

ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the totals you can `group by ordernumber` to get the last `eventdate` and then find the difference from the corresponding `orderdate`.
Then use UNION ALL:

```
select t.OrderNumber, t.DayDiff
from (
  select ordernumber nr, cast(ordernumber as varchar(10)) OrderNumber, null DayDiff, 0 col 
  from order_audit
  union all
  select a.ordernumber nr, 'Total', datediff(day, o.orderdate, a.eventdate) DayDiff, 1 col
  from orders o inner join (
    select 
    ordernumber, max(eventdate) eventdate
    from order_audit
    group by ordernumber
  ) a on a.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
) t
order by t.nr, t.col
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ba7c5d34297cff371e2198ab25ed826).
Results:

```
> OrderNumber | DayDiff
> :---------- | ------:
> 1           |    
> 1           |    
> 1           |    
> 1           |    
> 1           |    
> Total       |      14
> 2           |    
> 2           |    
> 2           |    
> 2           |    
> 2           |    
> Total       |      19
> 3           |    
> 3           |    
> 3           |    
> 3           |    
> 3           |    
> Total       |      21
> 4           |    
> 4           |    
> 4           |    
> 4           |    
> 4           |    
> Total       |       4
> 5           |    
> 5           |    
> 5           |    
> 5           |    
> 5           |    
> Total       |      32
```